# PHPExcel - Applying styles to many cells faster

Tags: performance, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to create a spreadsheet with approximately 20,000 cells. Some of these cells are styled red. In order to apply the red style, I'm iterating through an array of cell references:

```
foreach ($notCheapest as $cellRef) {
    $sheet->getStyle($cellRef)->applyFromArray([
        'font' => [
            'color' => ['rgb' => 'a00000']
        ]
    ]);
}
```

While this works, it's really quite slow. Is there a way of passing an array of cell references to PHPExcel with the style attached? I'm guessing calling a getter 1000's of times and the applyFromArray() method is what's causing the slowness here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of passing an array of cell references to PHPExcel with the style attached?

No, but if you have blocks of consecutive cells, you can specify a range rather than individual cells, and that's far more efficient:

```
$sheet->getStyle('B2:C5')->applyFromArray([
    'font' => [
        'color' => ['rgb' => 'a00000']
    ]
]);
```

because it's just a single request for all the cells in that range, and the style is then applied to that range of cells, not to each cell indiviually, so it's far more memory efficient as well as speed efficient

Comment: Thanks Mark, that makes sense. I don't think it's feasible for me to calculate regions (certainly can't be done quickly) - I'll live with the speed and perhaps implement a queue or something for users to download spreadsheets..

Comment: Also, thanks for speaking at phpcambridge recently :) Didn't think I'd be using phpexcel so soon! Great package :)

Comment: If it takes any length of time to generate spreadsheets, I'd recommend doing it as a back-end process and mailing the results to users, or otherwise notify them when the file is available for download

Comment: And it was my pleasure giving that talk; I always enjoy showing just how easy it is to contribute to open source projects